# How to monitor runtime behavior of OpenCL host code

Tags: opencl, feature-extraction

I need to run a big test suite of OpenCL host codes and kernels, and I need to extract some features from each execution.

I 've managed to extract static features from the kernel source files, but now I need to extract information from the host code that runs them as well, such as total bytes transferred between the host and the device, number of times the kernel is applied (# of iterations) etc.

Is there something that can help me or do I have to implement something from scratch? I haven't managed to find anything so far, even though it sounds like something that could live somewhere out there...

Answer (score -1):

Check into Intel's OpenCL intercept layer. I think it can capture at least some of what you are looking for and log it. https://github.com/intel/opencl-intercept-layer